# Prevent jumping to hash on initial load of URL consisting a hash

Tags: javascript, hash, scroll, hashchange, anchor-scroll

It is possible to prevent jumping to hash when hash changes with the following function for example:

```
function handleHashChange() {
   const scrollY = window.pageYOffset;
   window.scrollTo({top: scrollY});
}
```

But this only works if the hash is changed later. When a page with a URL **that already consists a hash** is loaded, this does not work. (For example: mysite.com/posts/#popular) I guess maybe because native `hashchange` event is sent to Callback Queue before custom `hashchange` event listener is added.

Is there any workaround to this problem ?

Answer (score 0):

So, it appears that, all that needs to be done is calling that scroll function inside `load` event listener:

```
window.addEventListener('load',()=>{
    const scrollY = window.pageYOffset;
      setTimeout(() => {
        window.scrollTo({top: scrollY});
      }, 0);
  });
```